# Explaining TypeScript Linter Errors

Tags: typescript

The web essentials plugin for visual studio 2013 comes with a linter for typescript. I get hundreds of messages now, but I have no idea what some of them mean.

Is there a place where every tslint error is explained? (a sort of tslint wiki?) I tried googling them, but I don't get any explanation.

Errors:

- **TsLint: expected callSignature to have a typedef.**
- **TsLint: missing 'use strict'** (I have a 'use strict' at the top of the file, which triggers the next error)
- **TsLint: expected an assignment or function call** (at 'use strict';)

and then there are some really weird ones:

- **TsLint: comment must start with a space** (really? why?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> sort of tslint wiki?

Unfortunately no. But a short description ins present here https://github.com/palantir/tslint#supported-rules

Many of these are from jslint so this should help http://jslinterrors.com/

> TsLint: comment must start with a space (really? why?)

It is a coding convention to make comments visually pleasing. `// comment` Is much easier to read than `//comment`. Visual aesthetics become important in large teams.

Comment: I got tons of TsLint: interface name must start with capital I. In my project I will always import a bunch of type definition files for JQuery, Knockout, etc so I will have a lot of interfaces that doesn't start with an I. Is there any way to tell TsLint to skip certain warnings?

Comment: You can add /* tslint:disable */ at the top of the file.

Comment: Is it possible to configure Visual Studio's tslint? According to the tslint documentation you can turn on/off features, example: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/docs/sample.tslint.json. But how do you accomplish this in VS?

Comment: But why does it complain about a tab instead of a space? :(